# Problemas com cache react native

Tags: react, react-native

Estou tendo problemas com cache no react native. Quando faço o upload de uma imagem para o servidor, tudo certo. A imagem que eu salvei aparece na tela inicial do App. Porém quando eu coloco uma outra imagem no lugar, esta nova imagem não aparece, e sim continua aparecendo a antiga. Então fui nas configuração do celular, gerenciador de aplicações, selecionei o aplicativo instalado e limpei o cache. Após fazer isso a nova imagem apareceu. Mas gostaria de saber se tem como fazer isso na programação ou algum comando no projeto para não permitir o armazenamento de cache.

Comment: A imagem está alocada nas sources do projeto ou é um url?

Comment: Eu puxo a imagem por URL

Comment: Qual a versão do android na AVD?

Comment: Tentei na 7.1 e 6.0